„Liegen an" vs „liegen in" mit zwei Phrasen der Begründung
Ich bin dabei, mir einige Phrasen zu merken, die von der Begründung handeln, und ich habe eine kurze Frage über zwei von diesen:


Das könnte daran liegen, dass...

Die Ursachen dafür liegen in etwas (Dat)



Ich habe bemerkt, dass mit der ersten Phrase man „an" benutzt und mit der anderen „in".  Könnte man beides in beiden Phrasen benutzen?

1a) Das könnte darin liegen, dass...
2a) Die Ursachen dafür liegen an etwas (Dat)

1a scheint mir gut zu sein, aber 2a klingt komisch.
Wenn sie nicht austauschbar sind, gibt es einen Grund, warum man „an" in dem einen Fall und „in" im anderen benutzt?  Oder ist es „einfach so", und man muss sich das alles merken?

1a) klingt für mich auch komisch, weil "an etwas liegen" einfach eine etablierte sehr gebräuchliche Phrase ist.
Ein klarer Unterschied zwischen den beiden Phrasen ist, dass bei 1 die Kausalität bereits in "an" und "liegen" steckt, während bei 2 das "liegen in" gewissermaßen nur eine Ortsangabe ist.

Hier steht dasselbe Verb, liegen, in zwei verschiedenen Konstruktionen:

X liegt [an Y]
X liegt [in Y]

Da die Präpositionen verschieden sind, sind die Satzbedeutungen verschieden. Die Verbindung "in Y liegen" hat "in" als eine Ortsangabe ("die Schokolade liegt in der Schublade"), das wird aber auch gern figurativ, in übertragenem Sinn gebraucht: "Die Ursache liegt in der steigenden Wassertemperatur" (das kann man sich noch bildlich vorstellen: man findet die Ursache, wenn man in die Situation mit der Wassertemperatur hineinschaut). Das Subjekt ist hier austauschbar, aber wenn das Subjekt "Ursache" lautet, ergibt sich allmählich eine konventionelle, abgeschwächte Bedeutung: "die Ursache liegt in Y" = "die Ursache IST Y". Man deutet es dann nur noch als Gleichsetzung, nicht als räumliche Beziehung, aber hier gibt es einen allmählichen Übergang.
Wenn man eine Begründung formuliert als "an Y liegen", gibt es (für mein Gefühl) keinen Zusammenhang mit einer räumlichen Angabe: "Der Temperaturanstieg liegt an Y" scheint also nicht einmal eine übertragene Bedeutung von Nähe zu haben (auf einer Grundlage wie "das Schiff liegt an der Hafenmauer"). Man würde "an Y" dann als Präpositionalobjekt bezeichnen, d.h. eine Bedeutungsvariante des Verbs hat eine feste Verbindung mit einer Präposition, die nur noch anzeigt, dass das eine Ergänzung des Verbs ist. So wie "auf etwas warten" – hingegen im Englischen wörtlich "für etwas warten" / wait for something – die Präpositionen sind einfach unterschiedlich festgelegt und lassen sich nicht inhaltlich erklären.
Die spezielle Rolle, die die Ergänzung mit "an" beim Verb nun spielt, ist gerade die Angabe einer Ursache. Wenn du sagst: "X liegt an Y", dann führt das "an" eine Ursache ein, das ist die festgelegte Rolle, die das Präpositionalobjekt bei dem Verb hat. Deswegen erscheint das Wort "Ursache" hier gar nicht extra! Dieser Begriff ist nun in die Bedeutung der Konstruktion eingebaut. – Wenn du aber sagst: "die Ursache von X liegt in Y", dann könnte man auch ein anderes Subjekt in dieser Konstruktion verwenden: "der Nachteil von X liegt in... / die Bedeutung von X liegt in... / die Attraktivität von X liegt in..." Diese Konstruktion ist nicht auf Ursachen festgelegt.
Es ergibt sich:

"Die Ursache von X liegt in Y" = "X liegt an Y".

Die Gesamtbedeutungen der Sätze sind ähnlich, aber der Aufbau ist nicht gleichartig, deswegen kann man hier die verwendeten Ausdrücke nicht mischen oder einfach auswechseln.
